# Keeping time in Obj-C

Tags: ios, nstimer

so I have a label and a string that keeps on growing. Every time the string adds something to itself, I want to add a time stamp, and my question is what is the best way of doing that. I tried having an NSTimer that just adds int's up every .001 seconds, but the problem is that when my app slows down so does the time keeping, so it isn't very accurate. Any other ideas? heres the code I tried:

in view did load:

```
if (debugTimeTimer.isValid != true) {
    debugTimeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(addTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

The addTime:

```
-(void) addTime {
debugMilli = debugMilli + 1;

if (debugMilli >= 1000) {
    debugSec = debugSec + 1;
    debugMilli = 0;
}

if (debugSec >= 60) {
    debugMin = debugMin + 1;
    debugSec = 0;
}
}
```

Where it adds to the string:

```
if (debugMin >=1) {
     debugTextString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i:%i     %@\r%@",debugMin, debugSec, debugMilli, charString, debugTextString];
} else {
    debugTextString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i     %@\r%@",debugSec, debugMilli, charString, debugTextString];
}
```

Comment: Also I have a segment of code that limits the size of the string so that it doesn't get to long so that doesn't seem to be helping very much

Comment: In that case, I don't know why it's slowing down. One other thing to note here, the time will drift because `NSTimer` isn't guaranteed to fire at the scheduled time, but at the scheduled time or after, whenever the system and application are able to get to it. For more accurate time keeping, you'll want to use `[NSDate date]` to grab the current time and if you're keeping a timer you'll want to capture the start time with `[NSDate timeintervalsince1970]` and compare it with the time interval from the start date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best function for this task is [`CACurrentMediaTime`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CACurrentMediaTime), which is part of the QuartzCore framework.  The return value is a `double` that represents time in seconds, with sub-millisecond accuracy.

If you store an initial reading from `CACurrentMediaTime` when the app starts, then you can subtract that initial value from subsequent readings to get the relative time from app startup. To get the time in milliseconds, multiply by 1000.0

For example, if you define a property

```
@property (nonatomic) CFTimeInterval startTime;
```

and initialize that property in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.startTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
```

then you can generate time stamps in milliseconds with code like this

```
uint64_t timeStampInMilliseconds;

CFTimeInterval delta = CACurrentMediaTime() - self.startTime;
timeStampInMilliseconds = delta * 1000.0;
NSLog( @"%llu", timeStampInMilliseconds );
```

You could also break the timestamp down into minutes, second, and milliseconds with code like this

```
uint64_t temp, milliseconds, seconds, minutes;
temp = timeStampInMilliseconds;
milliseconds = temp % 1000;
temp /= 1000;
seconds = temp % 60;
minutes = temp / 60;
NSLog( @"%llu:%02llu.%03llu", minutes, seconds, milliseconds );
```

Comment: There is a problem with this though. I am trying to get the time and add it to the string inside of a c function, and so using self.starttime doesn't work because self is undeclared.

Comment: Great, that worked, but one more question. Is there anyway to make it how minutes, seconds, and milliseconds? I could see how to do that, but the problem is the milliseconds keep join. Like once they get to  thousand I want them to turn into seconds and then go back to zero and so on.

Comment: @Chaus -- I added a little extra to the answer to show how to break the timestamp down into various components.

Answer (score 0):

```
void printf_to_debug (char* fmt, ...) {

va_list args;
va_start( args, fmt );

vprintf(fmt, args);

charString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@(fmt) arguments:args];

va_end( args );


//time ch
static CFTimeInterval startTime = -1.0;

if ( startTime < 0.0 )
    startTime = CACurrentMediaTime();

uint64_t timeStampInMilliseconds;

CFTimeInterval delta = CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime;
timeStampInMilliseconds = delta * 1000.0;
NSLog( @"%llu", timeStampInMilliseconds );


if (debugMin >=1) {
     debugTextString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i:%i     %@\r%@",debugMin, debugSec, debugMilli, charString, debugTextString];
} else {
    debugTextString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i     %@\r%@",debugSec, debugMilli, charString, debugTextString];
}



}
```

Comment: You could use a static variable instead. I'll edit the code to demonstrate.